# I am getting error when adding npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Error:

```
An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.paydevs.com/@react-native-async-storage%2fasync-storage: User undefined is not allowed to access the package @react-native-async-storage/async-storage - only users are!".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/daivik/projects/react-native/khetHisabPro/yarn-error.log".
```

yarn-error.log

Arguments:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/bin/yarn.js install -unfafe
```

PATH:

```
/Users/daivik/.gem/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:/usr/bin/ruby:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/daivik/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/daivik/.yarn/bin:/Users/daivik/.yarn-config/global/node_modules/.bin
```

Yarn version:
1.22.19

Node version:
16.17.0

Platform:
darwin arm64

Trace:

```
  Error: https://npm.paydevs.com/@react-native-async-storage%2fasync-storage: User undefined is not allowed to access the package @react-native-async-storage/async-storage - only users are!
      at Request.params.callback [as _callback] (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/lib/cli.js:66145:18)
      at Request.self.callback (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/lib/cli.js:140890:22)
      at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/lib/cli.js:141862:10)
      at Request.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/1.22.19/libexec/lib/cli.js:141784:12)
      at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
      at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

npm manifest:

```
  {
    "name": "khetHisabPro",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "android": "react-native run-android",
      "ios": "react-native run-ios",
      "start": "react-native start",
      "test": "jest",
      "lint": "eslint ."
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
      "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.7.0",
      "@react-native-firebase/app-check": "^16.7.0",
      "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.5.0",
      "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.3.1",
      "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
      "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
      "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
      "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.1",
      "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.6",
      "axios": "^1.2.1",
      "compare-versions": "^6.0.0-rc.1",
      "expo-linear-gradient": "^11.4.0",
      "firebase": "^9.15.0",
      "moment": "^2.29.4",
      "moment-timezone": "^0.5.40",
      "react": "18.1.0",
      "react-native": "0.70.6",
      "react-native-compress-image": "^2.0.1",
      "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.6",
      "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
      "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.6",
      "react-native-file-viewer": "^2.1.5",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
      "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.12.0",
      "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
      "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.39.0",
      "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.3.3",
      "react-native-keyboard-avoiding-scroll-view": "^1.0.1",
      "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
      "react-native-localization": "^2.3.1",
      "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.4",
      "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
      "react-native-razorpay": "^2.3.0",
      "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
      "react-native-redux": "^1.0.11",
      "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
      "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
      "react-native-simple-toast": "^2.0.0",
      "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
      "react-native-svg": "^13.6.0",
      "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.0",
      "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
      "react-native-video": "^5.2.1",
      "react-native-video-player": "^0.14.0",
      "react-native-webview": "^12.0.2",
      "react-native-youtube": "^2.0.2",
      "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
      "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
      "redux-persist-transform-filter": "^0.0.22",
      "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
      "victory-native": "^36.6.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
      "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
      "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
      "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
      "eslint": "^7.32.0",
      "jest": "^26.6.3",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
      "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "react-native"
    }
  }
```

yarn manifest:
No manifest

Lockfile:
No lockfile

Comment: Paydevs requires an account and payment. Either make an account over there and make sure you're logged in, or use the default registry.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by this command "npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/"

Answer (score 0):

From a comment by original poster:

> I have resolved this issue by this command "npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org"

The issue would seem to be that they were configured to use the paydevs.com repository rather than the free npm registry that is used by default.